# Codename One: Background Location Listener not firing on Android Lollipop

Tags: codenameone

I'm building an app that should periodically capture the user's location (I'm looking for every 60 minutes), tracking the cities they've visited.

I first started off using the foreground location listener and it was perfect, it seems to fire every few minutes but I've put checks in place so that it only actually tracks a location if enough time has passed. When I switch to other apps it looks like the foreground listener will continue to fire for a period of time, and then just stop firing, which to me makes sense since I'm thinking the OS is backgrounding the app. At which point, I would expect the background listener to have been registered and wake the app when that listener is fired.

On to my question... I'm having trouble with the background location listener. I understand that it won't fire on simulator, but it's also not firing when I build debug (using built-in certificate) to my device. For the sake of this question I've distilled what my app is doing down to barebones, based off the example listed here: https://gist.github.com/shannah/86c739edac34216d3c4d

Just to be sure I tried switching the background listener to the standard foreground one (.setLocationListener(new BackgroundListener())), and running on the simulator, I can verify that my label gets updated with appropriate data.

I also had done some testing on my actual app where I would pop a dialog in the no-arg constructor to say the listener was initialized, and another dialog when locationUpdated was called. I was able to see the popup on init, but there was no dialog on locationUpdated, which led me to believe my device was never firing it.

The device I'm testing on is a Samsung S4 with Android 5.0.1 (Lollipop).

Here is the test application I wrote which closely mimics what my actual application is doing.

bglocation.java

```
package com.bglocation;


import java.util.List;

import com.codename1.io.Storage;
import com.codename1.location.LocationManager;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class bglocation {
    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World");


        LocationManager.getLocationManager().setBackgroundLocationListener(BackgroundLocationListener.class);

        String lastCheckin = (String)Storage.getInstance().readObject("LOCATION");

        String label = "No checkins.";
        if (lastCheckin != null) {
            label = lastCheckin;
        }

        Label hiLabel = new Label("Last checkin: " + label);
        hi.addComponent(hiLabel);
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

BackgroundLocationListener.java

```
package com.bglocation;

import java.util.Date;

import com.codename1.io.Storage;
import com.codename1.location.Location;
import com.codename1.location.LocationListener;

public class BackgroundLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void locationUpdated(Location location) {
        Storage.getInstance().writeObject("LOCATION", new Date().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void providerStateChanged(int newState) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The background listener is invoked once there is a significant location change, it is also running on a completely different process so you don't really have a UI or access to your application instance.
What you need to do to communicate with your app is firing a local notification or launching an intent or storing the location into a file or a database and once your app is launched get the data from there.

Comment: Could you define significant location change please? Also, is there any restriction on where I can store the data that I receive? I'm intending to use the Storage class to write files at the root of wherever it stores files for my application, so I'm assuming it's accessible to both the Listener and my application.

Comment: on Android the background request is defined to 10 sec interval and 50 meters change, on iOS it is mapped to the significant location change callback which means when the device detects changes to the device’s associated cell tower

Comment: I updated my example in the original post such that the Listener will now just write to storage, and in the start() (which gets called every time the app unsuspends) I read from that same location, and it's still not working, could you please assist? 

I've created a new build and pushed it to my device, I ensured that the app was not stopped throughout the day (verified by holding home button to show running apps). I opened the app three times today: before I left for work, at work (~15km away), and then again when I returned home, and the label didn't update even if I force-quit/re-opened.

Comment: Hi @Chen, any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm absolutely stumped on why it's not working.

Comment: Turns out a bug in the framework caused by an old Android bug (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81812) was causing the issue. Chen has since added the change to the CN1 framework, and everything is working as expected.